# Trying to setup a gateway via pppoe

Tags: pppoe

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a computer. I want to use this computer as a router for my other computers. The computer only has 1 network card, there is no slot for a second card. I can get the computer to connect to my ISP via pppoe and it can access the web. However the other computers on my local net can only see the router computer. I have tried 2 different pppoe packages, roaring penguin and network-manager-gnome.

When I get it to work I will be replacing a 15 year old computer that is running Slackware 7.1. The old computer is currently my router. It is running Roaring Penguin> I tried to setup the new computer with the same Roaring Penguin parameters as the old computer.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing the network card eg: if it is currently eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces you can add an alias eg: br0 and set the network parameters for your internal network on this
Read The Documentation  Ubuntu Help Server Guide 12.04 - for further complete docs for your situation

Comment: I did set up an eth0:0 device. but that did not help. I have read the Guide but I am still lost.